# Convert a jQuery plugin into function and move inside existing JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below I have the basic structure for a JavaScript project and below that is a small jQuery plugin library.

My goal is to basically integrate the bottom jQuery plugin into my JavaScript project below.

In the project code below the jQuery plugin is called inside the `get_social_counts` function.  IF the jQuery plugin could be converted into a regular function and put into the project then the call to it inside of `get_social_counts` could be updated to simply call a function from the same object.

I am not sure how to integrate the jQuery plugin into my code though any help appreciated.

**JS library**

```
var SocialShareButtons = {

  init: function() {
    this.getPageDataToShare();
    this.build_social_btn_html();
    this.buildShareWindow();
  },

  get_social_counts: function(thisUrl) {

            $('.sharedCount .count').countTo({
                from: 0,
                to: totalCount,
                speed: 1000,
                refreshInterval: 5,
                formatter: function (value, options) {
                    return value.toFixed(options.decimals);
                },
            });

  },

  ////////////// several other functions.......

}
```

**jQuery Plugin**

```
  $.fn.countTo = function (options) {
    options = options || {};

    return $(this).each(function () {
      // set options for current element
      var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.countTo.defaults, {
        from:            $(this).data('from'),
        to:              $(this).data('to'),
        speed:           $(this).data('speed'),
        refreshInterval: $(this).data('refresh-interval'),
        decimals:        $(this).data('decimals')
      }, options);

      // how many times to update the value, and how much to increment the value on each update
      var loops = Math.ceil(settings.speed / settings.refreshInterval),
        increment = (settings.to - settings.from) / loops;

      // references & variables that will change with each update
      var self = this,
        $self = $(this),
        loopCount = 0,
        value = settings.from,
        data = $self.data('countTo') || {};

      $self.data('countTo', data);

      // if an existing interval can be found, clear it first
      if (data.interval) {
        clearInterval(data.interval);
      }
      data.interval = setInterval(updateTimer, settings.refreshInterval);

      // initialize the element with the starting value
      render(value);

      function updateTimer() {
        value += increment;
        loopCount++;

        render(value);

        if (typeof(settings.onUpdate) == 'function') {
          settings.onUpdate.call(self, value);
        }

        if (loopCount >= loops) {
          // remove the interval
          $self.removeData('countTo');
          clearInterval(data.interval);
          value = settings.to;

          if (typeof(settings.onComplete) == 'function') {
            settings.onComplete.call(self, value);
          }
        }
      }

      function render(value) {
        var formattedValue = settings.formatter.call(self, value, settings);
        $self.text(formattedValue);
      }
    });
  };

  $.fn.countTo.defaults = {
    from: 0,               // the number the element should start at
    to: 0,                 // the number the element should end at
    speed: 1000,           // how long it should take to count between the target numbers
    refreshInterval: 100,  // how often the element should be updated
    decimals: 0,           // the number of decimal places to show
    formatter: formatter,  // handler for formatting the value before rendering
    onUpdate: null,        // callback method for every time the element is updated
    onComplete: null       // callback method for when the element finishes updating
  };

  function formatter(value, settings) {
    return value.toFixed(settings.decimals);
  }
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noting it's only a counter to update DOM, I think you could just have re written the logic.

As a jquery plugin this would have applied to every selected dom element. Using the following, you would need to use a loop here or modify the function itself for multiple elements.

Hope the following helps... JS Function:

```
function countTo(dom, to, from, speed, refreshInterval, todecimals) {

    var loops = Math.ceil(speed / refreshInterval),
        increment = (to - from) / loops,
        loopCount = 0,
        value = from,
        timer;

    if (timer) clearInterval(timer);
    timer = setInterval(updateTimer, refreshInterval);

    render(value);

    function updateTimer() {
        value += increment;
        loopCount++;
        render(value);

        if (loopCount >= loops) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            value = to;
        }
    }

    function render(value) {
        dom.textContent = value.toFixed(todecimals);
    }
}
```

And you can call it with:

```
var domElement = $('.sharedCount .count')[0];

countTo(domElement, 0, totalCount, 1000, 5, options.decimals);
```

Comment: thanks that is exactly my goal as I am using it in my own library now so it is easier to have it as a function of my own code instead of a separate jQuery plugin that my code is dependent on.  IT works perfect, thanks